# "Register this connections address in DNS" - unable to automatically tick this box with a VPN connection

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, vpn, dhcp, rras

Hoping you can help. We have about 70 Microsoft Surface's in our network and they all have a VPN connection that is deployed from our SCCM 2012 Server. the problem I have is they will not update DNS with the address they obtain from DHCP when connecting through the VPN. I have setup my DHCP to provide IP's to the VPN Server (RRAS) and dynamically update DNS but this does not work unless I actually tick the `Register this connections address in DNS` box on the client itself.

I am aware there is a PowerShell command to change this setting `SetDynamicDNSRegistration` method of the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` however, it is not able to find the VPN connection unless it is actually connected. I've read this is a "Bug" within windows that they have not bothered to fix.

Is there any other way to get this working without having to go to every one of the 70 machines and ticking the box? As soon as I tick that box it works perfectly, but I don't want to have to do that manually 70 times.

Comment: I would recommend a scheduled task, as it seems easiest.  Push out by GPO, and every X minutes, check if the VPN is connected.  If so, check the Dynamic DNS Registration, and set it, if not set.